# Choose only one of the multiple og:image to post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to have multimple og:image for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMGURL 1" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMGURL 2" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMGURL 3" />
```

And then call only one v the sharer.php to show it on the timeline?

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=URL&p[images][0]=URL&p[title]=TEXT">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check your site with the [open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), there you can see the image that is fetched by the facebook crawler.

facebook want's to spread the og:meta-tags more and more, so facebook often ignores parameters in your sharer.php-url. for more info to the share-buttons take a look at [facebook-share buttons](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

you can use it without the share-button (text-only link)

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank"> Share on Facebook
</a>`

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple share buttons on the same page but that each one share a different picture?

Comment: i dont think so, multiple og:images would override each other